# choose a dynamic item in a dropdown without losing choice upon submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every time I click an ASP button on my page to select an item in my dropdown list, it is only choosing the first item in the list.  It is as if every time I click a button the page refreshes and all variables reset. How do you choose an item from a dropdown when using dynamic data from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds indicative of populating the `DropDownList` in `Page_Load`.  Is that the case?  (I'm assuming you're using WebForms.)  If you're populating the control in `Page_Load` then you'll want to wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  // populate your controls from data
}
```

Otherwise, they'll get re-populated with each postback.  When you click a button or perform some other action on the page which initiates a postback, `Page_Load` is called *before* the event handler.  So in effect, this is happening:

1. User navigates to the page
2. `Page_Load` clears and re-populates the `DropDownList`
3. User chooses an item in the `DropDownList`
4. User clicks a button
5. `Page_Load` clears and re-populates the `DropDownList`
6. Button handler gets the current selection from the `DropDownList`, which is the default.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what it was meant with "pressing a button". Very good guess!!

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: I consider this to be my single largest complaint about WebForms.  So many baffled developers, so many meaningless conditionals in code, so much clutter in application after application around the world :)

Comment: Agree. In my last ASP.NET project I have about 12 "ifs" in `Page_Load` method, checking for PostBack, routing parameters, session data etc...

Comment: Yup...thanks.  Very very different than the PHP I am used to.

Comment: @Geekender: Oh yes, different in many ways.  WebForms was Microsoft's way of applying the event-driven style of Windows application development to the web platform.  I believe it's very unique in that regard.  While still very different from PHP, you might find ASP.NET's MVC Framework to be more intuitive in many ways.  The inline code in Views will be more familiar to you, and the fact that Controller actions are called directly without lots of event wiring getting in the way will probably make more sense.

Comment: Can you change from Webforms to MVC once you have built the application?

Comment: @Geekender: The two can co-mingle in a single application, allowing for gradual migration.  But you'll want a pretty deep understanding of both of them and of .NET project structures in general before doing that.  Personally I'd prefer to develop the updated application separately and handle the gradual migration between the two by means of a kind of single sign-on between them so users don't know or care that they're jumping back and forth between two different applications.

Comment: I tried the !isPostback and still get the same behavior.  I can populate the dropdown and even submit the value, but it is that first value that gets submitted.

Comment: @Geekender: Can you show more complete code in the question?  Include `Page_Load`, the event handler, the page controls, etc. (But exclude anything not related.  Basically, reproduce the problem with minimal code.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "click ASP button"?

If you are talking about the downarrow to open the dropdown list, then you need to set `AutoPostback` options to `false` if you don't want that opening the dropdown list triggers postback (that is on the other side required if you have any events related to the opening of your list).